# Find DC current through the diodes

Tags: diodes

I am trying to perform the DC analysis of the following circuit:

[image]

Since we are performing the DC analysis, the ac voltage sources will be grounded. I have drawn the schematic when AC source is grounded. I am not able to find how the current I will be divided between D1, D2, D3, D4. Please give answers in terms of I. (Please forgive me for my schematic diagram where I have placed nodes in place of arrows)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwBKUg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: One of your diodes is wrong...

Comment: It’s ok………………..

Comment: Since this looks like a homework question we will expect you to show us that you have made a substantial effort to solve this yourself. Show us all of your work and then ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Two current sources in series might be different by some error and unbalance the diode voltage.

e.g. if I2 was raised 10% to 11 mA then 1mA is pulled from R1=1k and it’s vo is now -1V.

**But if diodes are same and I’s are equal , vo=vi=0V regardless of I1=I2 levels.**

This because all diodes conduct equal current and shared so 5mA each. vi is a 0 V 0 ohm reference therefore the voltage across each diode is the same being +0.7 on the Anode side of I1 and -0.7V on the common cathode side connected to I2. thus vo is the middle = 0V same as vi.

- all diodes are forward biased in this circuit.

For an AC bridge the input is normally vo to vi as inputs but this has inputs with reverse current applied to the otherwise DC outputs.

This circuit could eliminate I2 and just have a 0 Ohm ammeter and achieve the same results.

Comment: Sir, can you please mention why is vo = vi ?

Comment: @AnwesaRoy Since this looks like a homework question we will expect you to show us that you have made a substantial effort to solve this yourself. Show us all of your work and then ask a specific question.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Sir, The question asked us to find vo/vi, which means we have to do both DC and AC analysis. I have figured out how to do the AC analysis. For DC analysis, I have drawn the equivalent AC circuit diagram, which is the second figure. For there, I am not able to discern how the current will be divided among the diodes. Once I know how the current has been distributed, I will be able to do the AC analysis.

Comment: For AC analysis, the diode  impedance which depends on DC bias current https://tinyurl.com/yg5ukhwa in series relative to load  R